# Angle bisector of two vectors in 3D

Tags: matlab, math

I don't know how to calculate the angle bisector of two vectors (that defined by 3 points) in 3D.
example:
my points are:

```
P1=[0 0 0];
p2=[26.94,-6.68,42.76];
P3=[7.2804  -11.1231   46.6817];
```

p2 is the start point of the angle bisector .

[image]

```
p1=[0 0 0];
p2=[26.94,-6.68,42.76];
p3=[7.2804  -11.1231   46.6817];


V1=[(p1(1)-p2(1)) (p1(2)-p2(2)) (p1(3)-p2(3))];
V2=[(p2(1)-p3(1)) (p2(2)-p3(2)) (p2(3)-p3(3))];

V1=V1/norm(V1);
V2=V2/norm(V2);

Bisector=V1+V2;
figure
hold on

plot3([p3(3),p2(3)],[p3(2),p2(2)],[p3(1),p2(1)],'Color','r','LineWidth',2)
plot3([p1(3),p2(3)],[p1(2),p2(2)],[p1(1),p2(1)],'Color','r','LineWidth',2)

plot3([p2(3),Bisector(3)],[p2(2),Bisector(2)],[p2(1),Bisector(1)],'Color','y','LineWidth',2)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean?  The line that divides your line segment in two equal parts, and passes through the third point?  Or are you defining an infinite line and looking for the line that is normal to that line, and passes through your third point?

Comment: I am lookinig for the vector that divde the angle between the above vector to two equals parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your code above.  This should fix it.

```
V1=[(p1(1)-p2(1)) (p1(2)-p2(2)) (p1(3)-p2(3))];
V2=[(p3(1)-p2(1)) (p3(2)-p2(2)) (p3(3)-p2(3))];

V1=V1/norm(V1);
V2=V2/norm(V2);

Bisector=V1+V2;
figure
hold on

plot3([p3(3),p2(3)],[p3(2),p2(2)],[p3(1),p2(1)],'Color','r','LineWidth',2)
plot3([p1(3),p2(3)],[p1(2),p2(2)],[p1(1),p2(1)],'Color','r','LineWidth',2)

plot3([p2(3),Bisector(3)+p2(3)],[p2(2),Bisector(2)+p2(2)],[p2(1),Bisector(1)+p2(1)],'Color','y','LineWidth',2)
```

Note the two lines in **boldface**.

The first issue is essentially a sign issue.  You need to translate your vectors so `p2` is at the origin.  So, to get `V1` and `V2,` you subtract `p2` from `p1` and `p3` respectively.  You do this when computing `V1` but your are computing `V2=p2-p3` rather than `V2=p3-p2`.

The second issue is that your vector `Bisector` is translated relative to the an origin placed at `p2`.  Thus, you need to translate it back to the original coordinate system.  This is done simply by adding `p2` to your `Bisector` vector for display purposes.  This is what is now done in the last line.

Answer (score 8):

Normalize the vectors, and then add them. The resultant vector bisects the other two.

Comment: Thanks, when I do it i get   [0.42,0.34,-1.02], how can I plot it. I know how to plot two points.

Comment: please look at the code above. this not look like the angle bisector

Comment: It is. You know that you have to add the vector to the origin to get the second point, right?

Comment: Only if the initial vectors are not parallel